# Problema con "espacios extras" al escribir en archivos

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un pequeño problema al escribir en archivos. En mi programa al utilizar el boton `encriptar` el mensaje utiliza la función `guardarMensaje()` la primera vez funciona perfecto, pero luego al darle al botón `desencriptar` y volver a darle al boton `encriptar` se agregan "espacios extras" que no quiero que aparezcan en el archivo

Dato curioso: Si utilizo por primera vez el botón `encriptar`cierro el programa, lo vuelvo a abrir y vuelvo darle al botón `encriptar` esto de los "espacios extras" no ocurre

Por "espacios extras" me quiero referir a esto:
[image: "Espacios extras"]

PD: Quise reducir el tamaño del código, pero al hacerlo los espacios extras desaparecieron

```
import random
from random import shuffle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import END
from tkinter import INSERT
from tkinter import Message
from tkinter import messagebox
import os 
import os.path as path
import sys


class main():
    def __init__(self):
        ventana = self.ventana = Tk()
        ventana.geometry("500x500")

        self.listaKey = {}
        self.listaMensaje = {}

        self.encriptado = False
        self.desencriptado = True

        self.keys = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
        "m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","z","y","z"]


        labelMensaje = Label(ventana,text="Mensaje")
        labelMensaje.config(fg="red",bg="black")
        labelMensaje.place(x=150,y=0,width=200)

        self.textoMensaje = Text(ventana)
        self.textoMensaje.place(x=150,y=30,width=200)
        self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT,"Escribe lo que quieras.")

        botonEncriptar = ttk.Button(ventana,text="Encriptar",command=self.encriptar)
        botonEncriptar.place(x=400,y=100)

        botonDesencriptar = ttk.Button(ventana,text="Desencriptar",command=self.desencriptar)
        botonDesencriptar.place(x=400,y=150)

        botoncambiarKey = ttk.Button(ventana,text="Cambiar Key",command=self.cambiarKey)
        botoncambiarKey.place(x=400,y=200)

        self.cambiarKey()

        botonGuardar = ttk.Button(ventana,text="Guardar",command=self.guardarMensaje)
        botonGuardar.place(x=400,y=300)

        self.contarIds()

    def encriptar(self):
        if self.encriptado == False:
            cifrado = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
            "m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","z","y","z"]
            shuffle(cifrado)

            self.mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0,END)
            self.listaMensaje['Mensaje'] = self.mensajeOriginal
            self.listaKey['Key'] = self.keyI
            self.keyI = self.listaKey['Key']

            self.textoMensaje.delete(1.0,END)

            for i in self.mensajeOriginal:
                self.x = i.replace(i,random.choice(cifrado))
                self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT,self.x)

            self.keydeEncriptado = self.listaKey['Key']

            self.MensajeEncriptado = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0,END)

            self.encriptado = True
            self.desencriptado = False
            self.guardarMensaje()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","El mensaje ya esta incriptado")

    def desencriptar(self):
        if self.desencriptado == False:
            if self.keydeEncriptado == self.listaKey['Key']:
                self.textoMensaje.delete(1.0,END)
                self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT,self.mensajeOriginal)
                self.encriptado = False
                self.desencriptado = True
                self.listaKey.clear()
                self.listaMensaje.clear()

            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error","La key no es correcta")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","el mensaje ya esta desencriptado")

    def cambiarKey(self):
        self.keyI = random.choice(self.keys)
        self.listaKey['Key'] = self.keyI
        self.keyI = self.listaKey['Key']
        self.labelKey = ttk.Label(self.ventana,text="Key: " + self.keyI)
        self.labelKey.place(x=400,y=250)

    def leerLineas(self):
        archivo = open("Mensajes.txt","r")
        lineas = 0
        for linea in archivo:
            if linea == "\n":
                pass
            else:
                lineas += 1
        print(lineas)
        archivo.close()

    def contarIds(self):
        try:
            archivo = open("Mensajes.txt","r")
            self.contarIds = 0
            for linea in archivo:
                if linea == "\n":
                    pass
                if linea.find("Key"):
                    pass
                if linea.find("Mensaje"):
                    pass
                else:
                    self.contarIds += 1
            archivo.close()
        except:
            self.contarIds = 0
            pass

    def getmensajeEncriptado(self):
        return self.MensajeEncriptado

    def guardarMensaje(self):
        archivo = open("Mensajes.txt","a")
        self.contarIds += 1
        archivo.write("Id: "+ str(self.contarIds)+"\n")
        archivo.write("MEncriptado: "+ self.getmensajeEncriptado())
        for mensaje in self.listaMensaje:
            archivo.write(mensaje + ": " + self.listaMensaje[mensaje])
            for key in self.listaKey:
                archivo.write(key +": " + self.listaKey[key]+"\n")

        archivo.close()

gui = main()
gui.ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas hay algo que nos puede hacer sospechar, tras el primer bloque se agrega una línea, después del segundo se agregan dos, y así sucesivamente. Cada vez que encriptas sin modificar el contenido del `Entry` se añade una nueva linea en blanco...

El problema está realmente en la línea:

```
self.mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0, END)
```

- El primer argumento de `get`, `1.0` significa que debe leerse desde la línea uno, carácter cero. Nada raro con esto.
- El segundo argumento de `get`, `END` es una constante importada desde el espacio de nombres global de tkinter y que se establece en la cadena `'end'` (es decir, `self.textoMensaje.get(1.0, "end")` sería equivalente).

  Con `END` indicamos que debe leer hasta llegar al final del contenido del `Text`. El  problema con esto es que **el widget `Text` siempre agrega una nueva línea (`\n`) al texto que contiene**, por lo que usar `END` ocasiona que el carácter `\n` agregado sea también obtenido, cuando no formaaba parte del texto ingresado original.

Lo anterior ocasiona que al llamar repetidamente a `encriptar` sin modificar el contenido del `Text` se vayan agregando nuevas lineas con cada llamada a `get`. Lógicamente si borras el contenido del `Text`, vuelves a lanzar la aplicación o simplemente eliminas manualmente las nuevas lineas vacías tras cada llamada a encriptar lo anterior no ocurre.

Para solucionar el mencionado problema se debe cambiar `END` a `"end-1c"`, es decir "lee hasta el final del contenido del `Text` menos un carácter". Por lo tanto tu línea debe quedar:

```
self.mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0, "end-1c")
```

o también:

```
self.mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0, END + "-1c")
```